# Enabling ECS Exec thru Terraform and Encountering: InvalidParameterException: The service couldn't be updated because a valid taskRoleArn is not

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm new to Terraform and ECS and I'm trying to enable ECS Exec to debug my containers. I created my ECS instances using the Terraform below which launches perfectly fine on the latest terraform. When I add `enable_execute_command = true` to my ecs resource, I encounter the error below:

> InvalidParameterException: The service couldn't be updated because a
> valid taskRoleArn is not being used

I've tried different approaches from Google searches to no avail. Can anyone provide a Terraform configuration that can add ECS Exec access to the `ecsTaskExecutionRole` or a new role.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "my_first_ecr_repo" {
  name = "my-first-ecr-repo" 
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name = "my-first-cluster" 
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_first_task" {
  family                   = "my-first-task" 
  container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "my-first-task",
      "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.my_first_ecr_repo.repository_url}",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 3000
        }
      ],
      "memory": 512,
      "cpu": 256
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"] 
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"    Fargate
  memory                   = 512         
  cpu                      = 256         
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecsTaskExecutionRole" {
  name               = "ecsTaskExecutionRole"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecsTaskExecutionRole_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}


resource "aws_default_vpc" "default_vpc" {
}


resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_subnet_a" {
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_subnet_e" {
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b"
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "default_subnet_f" {
  availability_zone = "us-east-1c"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_first_service" {
  name            = "my-first-service"                             
  enable_execute_command = true
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster.id}"             
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.my_first_task.arn}" will spin up
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  desired_count   = 3 

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn}" 
    container_name   = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.my_first_task.family}"
    container_port   = 3000 
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = ["${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_a.id}", "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_e.id}", "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_f.id}"]
    assign_public_ip = true 
    security_groups  = ["${aws_security_group.service_security_group.id}"] 
  }
}


resource "aws_alb" "application_load_balancer" {
  name               = "test-lb-tf" 
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets = [ 
    "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_a.id}",
    "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_e.id}",
    "${aws_default_subnet.default_subnet_f.id}"
  ]
  
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id}"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "service_security_group" {
  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id}"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0 
    to_port     = 0 
    protocol    = "-1" 
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "load_balancer_security_group" {
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80 
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0 
    to_port     = 0 
    protocol    = "-1" 
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group" {
  name        = "target-group"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_default_vpc.default_vpc.id}" 
  health_check {
    matcher = "200,301,302"
    path = "/"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.application_load_balancer.arn}" 
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn}" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned a Task Execution Role. You have not assigned a Task Role. You have to have a Task Role assigned to the task that provides the necessary IAM permissions needed for ECS Exec to work. At a minimum, that role will need to have the following permissions:

```
      {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": [
            "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
       ],
       "Resource": "*"
      },
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html#ecs-exec-enabling-and-using).